# Inserir Json dentro de Json

Tags: java, json

Em uma estrutura cliente-servidor (em JAVA), tenho as seguintes estruturas Json separadamente (exemplo):
Estrutura de **Alunos**:

```
{"idAluno":1,"nomeAluno":"Teste da Silva","listaDeTurmas":[1,2]}
```

Estrutura de **Turmas**:

```
{"idTurma":1,"nomeTurma":"Redes"}
{"idTurma":2,"nomeTurma":"Compiladores"}
```

Cada estrutura é gerenciada por uma aplicação Java diferente. Uma outra aplicação faz requisições à cada uma delas. Após uma requisição à aplicação de **Alunos**, recebo como resposta a estrutura que referenciei acima. No caso de uma requisição de busca, preciso exibir na parte do Array de turmas do aluno, os dados da turma em questão. Exemplo:

```
{ 
    "idAluno": 1,
    "nomeAluno": "Teste da Silva",
    "listaDeTurmas": [
        {
            "idTurma": 1,
            "nomeTurma": "Redes"
        },
        {
            "idTurma": 2,
            "nomeTurma": "Compiladores"
        }
    ]
}
```

Para cada id de turma, faço uma requisição na aplicação de Turmas e recebo a estrutura correspondente da turma buscada.
Mas qual a forma correta de modificar o Array no Json do aluno e fazer com que sejam exibidos os dados da turma ao invés de simplesmente o código dela (conforme o exemplo acima)? Preciso desmembrar as duas estruturas e criar um novo Json a partir daí ou há uma forma mais simples de fazer isso?

Comment: Eu passaria o `JSONs` para objetos correspondentes na aplicação que esta fazendo a requisição, organizaria a lista de objetos Turma dentro do objeto Aluno, e ai montaria novamente a string `JSON` a partir do objeto Aluno. (_apenas uma das formas de solução_) :p

Comment: Só que o Array de turmas do meu objeto Aluno é um ArrayList de Integer. Eu teria que criar uma outra classe com ArrayList de String daí?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Uma ideia para a solução:**

1. Faz a requisição do JSON de Aluno e monta ele dentro de um objeto Aluno
2. Faz a requisição das Turmas, de acordo com as ids que você já tem.
3. Monta um objeto Turma de acordo com o que receber na requisição do JSON de turma.
4. Cria um novo campo no objeto Aluno do tipo `ArrayList<Turma>` e passa todos os objetos que você busco de Turma para esse array.
5. Gera o novo JSON a partir de Aluno, com a lista de Turmas já adicionada no objeto.

**Classes**

Atenção aqui: Crie **apenas o método set** da variavel `int[] listaDeTurmas` na classe Aluno para que ele não reproduza seu array de `int[]` quando você fizer a exportação da classe com as turmas mais tarde

```
public class Aluno {

  private int idAluno;
  private String nomeAluno;
  private int[] listaDeTurmas;

  private List<Turma> listaTurma = new ArrayList<>();

  public void setListaDeTurmas(int[] listaDeTurmas) {
      this.listaDeTurmas = listaDeTurmas;
  }
  //metodo para adicionar elemento a sua List
  public void addTurma(Turma t) {
      listaTurma.add(t);
  }
  //gets e sets das outras três variáveis...
}
```

---

```
public class Turma {

  private int idTurma;
  private String nomeTurma;

  //gets e sets...
}
```

---

Para reproduzir e facilitar o processo utilizei a biblioteca `Jackson` para quebrar o JSON

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public static void main(String[] args)  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        String alunoString = "{\"idAluno\":1,\"nomeAluno\":\"Teste da Silva\",\"listaDeTurmas\":[1,2]}";
        Aluno aluno = mapper.readValue(alunoString, Aluno.class);

        String turma1String = "{\"idTurma\":1,\"nomeTurma\":\"Redes\"}";
        Turma turma1 = mapper.readValue(turma1String, Turma.class);

        String turma2String = "{\"idTurma\":2,\"nomeTurma\":\"Compiladores\"}";
        Turma turma2 = mapper.readValue(turma2String, Turma.class);

        aluno.addTurma(turma1);
        aluno.addTurma(turma2);

        String jsonAlunoCompleto = mapper.writeValueAsString(aluno);
        System.out.println(jsonAlunoCompleto);
        //{"idAluno":1,"nomeAluno":"Teste da Silva","listaTurma":[{"idTurma":1,"nomeTurma":"Redes"},{"idTurma":2,"nomeTurma":"Compiladores"}]}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }

}
```

Comment: Estou tendo um erro ao tentar converter a string do aluno para a classe Aluno: _The type com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files_

Comment: Na verdade eu vinha usando a biblioteca Gson até então, e havia implementado algo parecido antes de vc editar o comentário. Criei um **ArrayList<Turma> turmas** no objeto Aluno e então faço a mesma coisa que vc sugeriu, porém usando os métodos _toJson_ e _fromJson_ para as conversões String <-> Classe (inclusive até os parâmetros passados são os mesmos).

Mas a resposta acaba saindo no mesmo formato (só com os ids das turmas).

Comment: Mas estou achando que o problema não é nessa parte da lógica...estou debuggando ainda.

Comment: Para resolver o primeiro erro de JsonParser, basta adicionar estas [libs](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core)

Comment: Para resolver o problema dele retornar as mesmas variáveis, certifique-se que você adicionou o metodo **set** para resgatar o `ArrayList` de turma

Comment: Sim, o set foi criado. E deixei apenas o _set_ do outro Array (no meu caso de Integer, que contém apenas os IDs), como vc disse.

Comment: Corrigi aquele primeiro erro com as libs (eu havia incluído apenas a _databind_). Mas executei teu código e o _jsonAlunoCompleto_ sai como **null**.

Comment: Vai precisar depurar e ver que objeto esta iniciando o erro, se é o _mapper_ que não consegue transformar, ou se é algum objeto Aluno ou Turma que esta nulo. Alem do null, a JVM lança alguma exception?